# The requested URL could not be retrieved "http://localhost/" <!-- ERR_ACCESS_DENIED --> using XAMPP

Tags: php, rest, proxy, xampp, localhost

I deployed my PHP Web Application on XAMPP. While it trying to retrieve the URL: http://localhost/, I get this error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> <html><head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <title>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</title> <style type="text/css"><!--  %l  body :lang(fa) { direction: rtl; font-size: 100%; font-family: Tahoma, Roya, sans-serif; float: right; } :lang(he) { direction: rtl; float: right; }  --></style> </head><body> <div id="titles"> <h1>ERROR</h1> <h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2> </div> <hr>  <div id="content"> <p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="http://localhost/api/rest.php">http://localhost/api/rest.php</a></p>  <blockquote id="error"> <p><b>Access Denied.</b></p> </blockquote>  <p>Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.</p>  <p>Your cache administrator is <a href="mailto:helpdesk.proxy%W">helpdesk.proxy</a>.</p> <br> </div>  <hr> <div id="footer"> <p>Generated Thu, 17 Sep 2015 08:30:50 GMT by proxy.it (squid/2.7.STABLE9)</p> <!-- ERR_ACCESS_DENIED --> </div> </body></html> <br />
```

I've read other topics. I already taken some tips like bypass proxy in LAN Settings and don't use proxy for these address (127.0.0.1;localhost;) in advanced settings.

But I get the same error.
I think that it need to do some configuration in XAMPP, but I don't know what set.

Thanks all

Comment: you tried to open http://localhost/api/rest.php ??? @vincent

Comment: I'm trying to open a url from localhost. In this topic, I intentionally deleted a portion of url. the full url is http://localhost/test/folder1/api/rest.php

Comment: Do index.php is opening? I mean any basic pages are opening??

Comment: Please share the file content you are trying to access. And its relative folder location too. @vincent

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535339/error-the-requested-url-could-not-be-retrieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. There were two environment variables HTTP and HTTPS set with proxy.

Comment: Can anyone explain the above answer briefly?