# ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel

I have a project in CodeIgniter and hosted in Sub-domain, and it has an error:

> The requested URL could not be retrieved

Here is a picture of it:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltBZB.png)

Comment: your question is not clear. Provide more details.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same error on a new installation of CodeIgniter. I solved this error by turning off my VPN browser plugin.
You might have a proxy or VPN app running turn it off and see.

Answer (score 1):

Below steps worked for me -

1. Search for Proxy Settings on windows machine
2. Disable all the proxy settings

Answer (score 0):

Please use this mandatory part before moving your code from localhost to live server.

1. Change `base_url` in config file.
2. Do necessary changes in `.htaccess` file
3. Change database connection `credentials`

This will help you.